# Creating iframe area with scroll bar

Tags: css, html

I want to create an iframe area with scroll bar as [like here](https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-timelines)

I checked html codes, and created iframe are like below. But area seems empty, when I put something inside. It's not showing on the screen.

```
 <iframe width="100%" height="315" allowfullscreen>
  <a class="twitter-timeline"
       data-lang="en" 
       href="https://twitter.com/username" 
       data-tweet-limit="10">
  </a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm fright">Follow Us on Twitter</a> 
</iframe>
```

Comment: why you need `iframe` you can do it with simple `div` .... is there any requirement of you just put it anyway?

Comment: Because I want to get ten tweet from user profiles. And these tweets make the sidebar too long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How the iframe works
No source nothing happens.

```
 <iframe src="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48841319/creating-iframe-area-with-scroll-bar" width="500" height="315" style="overflow-y:scroll;">
 </iframe>
```

Same thing using a div.  This is what you want unless it is another page you are trying to insert then use iframe or object.

CSS

```
.divExample{
overflow-y:scroll;
width:500px;
height:315px;
float:left;
border:thin #000000 solid;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="divExample">
<a class="twitter-timeline"
   data-lang="en" 
   href="https://twitter.com/username" 
   data-tweet-limit="10">
</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm fright">Follow Us on Twitter</a> 
</div>
```

Comment: I see.. I didin't know that we can create an scroll with div

Comment: You can add scroll to a lot of elements glad I could help